# Textbox return value of jquery dialog box

Tags: c#, jquery, textbox

```js
function reason_img(img) {
  jQuery(function() {
    $("<div></div>").toggle(function() {
      $("<div></div>")
        .append(
          $('<label>Reason: </label>')
          .offset({
            left: 25,
            top: 320
          })
        )
        .append(
          $("<input>")
          .attr({
            "type": "text",
            "id": "reason"
          })
          .offset({
            left: 25,
            top: 320
          })
        )
        .append(
          $("<img>")
          .attr({
            "src": img,
            "float": "left"
          })
        )
        .dialog({
          title: $("#name").val(),
          height: 'auto',
          width: 310,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              var a = $("#reason").val();
              $(this).dialog('close');
              $(this).remove();
              return a;
            }
          }
        });
    });
  });
  //return true;  
}
```

```html
reason.Text = ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "showalert", "reason_img('"+photo+"');", true);
```

I have a problem to let the textbox return the value of jquery dialog box which contains picture and textbox input.

I need to use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in order to call the jquery function from code behind. But i get error when i assign ScriptManager to textbox id

Expected outcomes:

1. user input the value in the textbox of the dialog box
2. targeted textbox inside form return value of user input the value in the textbox of the dialog box(1) .

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I get this error. CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Comment: Can you share the code too? ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript inject the JavaScript in aspx from server side. It does not return anything. Its return type is void that's why you are getting error.

Comment: i added the code already @ChetanRanpariya